# Why does the <picture> tag download an image twice?

Tags: html

I am using the picture element in HTML like so:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 375px)"
        srcset="http://mysite/-/media/Images/picture.ashx?mw=375">
    <source media="(max-width: 800px)"
        srcset="http://mysite/-/media/Images/picture.ashx?mw=800">
    <img src="http://mysite/-/media/Images/picture.ashx"
         alt="responsive image that doesn’t break your layout">
</picture>
```

I am using a CMS to handle media, thus the .ashx extension.  My CMS supports dynamically resizing images by appending a mw=X query string to call out max-width.  My default mage is a .png with width of 1280px.

This appears to work great in Chrome 46.x.  When I resize my viewport, the image shrinks appropriately to the various sizes.

What I'm confused on, is when I inspect network traffic (with both chrome and fiddler), I'm seeing my image downloaded twice.  I've used chrome to set my viewport to an iPhone 6s and performed a "Empty cache and hard reload".  What I see in fiddler is picture.ashx?mw=800 downloaded and then picture.ashx immediately following.

Screen shot from Chrome's network traffic: 
[image]

Why is my browser downloading the image twice?

Comment: Do you have a `meta viewport` and what does it say?

Comment: Does it happen in Chrome 47?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? I tested your code  in Chrome with my own images. `picture` element worked as designed; only one image loaded per viewport size.

Comment: There is no `meta viewport` set.  Could the .ashx extension be interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  When using device mode in Chrome, the image is downloaded twice.  If I just resize the browser window to a smaller size, it is not downloaded twice.  I think this is just a bug in the Device Viewport.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a script injected by a plugin inside my picture tag (rocket-loader), which for some reasons cause two images of the picture tag to be loaded.